# Azure move files from blob storage to file storage in the same storage account

Tags: c#, .net, azure, cloud, azure-blob-storage

I need to pass some files around, from the blob storage to the file storage. Both of these storages are in the same storage account. Here I get the **file** storage:

```
 var storage = GetStorageAccount(resourceGroup, storageName);
 CloudFileClient fileClient = storage.CreateCloudFileClient();
 CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference(projectId.ToString());
```

and we can assume that I also have a reference to the blob storage, as well as the uri of the file I want to move to the file storage. How can I do this, preferably without using AzCopy, but doing it from C# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work in the following way:

```
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storage.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("powershellscripts");
var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("WriteToFile.ps1");

SharedAccessBlobPolicy adHocSAS = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
        {
            // When the start time for the SAS is omitted, the start time is assumed to be the time when the storage service receives the request.
            // Omitting the start time for a SAS that is effective immediately helps to avoid clock skew.
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24),
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Create
        };
string sasBlobToken = blockBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(adHocSAS);
// Create a new file in your target file storage directory
CloudFile sourceFile = share.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetFileReference("MyExample.ps1");

Uri fileSasUri = new Uri(blockBlob.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.ToString() + sasBlobToken);
await sourceFile.StartCopyAsync(blockBlob);
```

So you first need to get a **token from the blob you want to copy**, and then just create a simple file in your target file storage directory, and call StartCopy.

Answer (score 2):

You may refer to the code which uses the same framework libraries:

First, include the classes you need, here we include Storage client library, the Storage data movement library and the .NET threading because data movement library provides Task Asynchronous interfaces to transfer storage objects:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement;
```

Now use the interfaces provided by Storage client lib to setup the storage context (find more details at how to use Blob Storage from .NET):

```
string storageConnectionString = "myStorageConnectionString";
CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
string sourcePath = "path\\to\\test.txt";
CloudBlockBlob destBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");
```

Once you setup the storage blob context, you can start to use WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferManager to upload the blob and track the upload progress,

```
// Setup the number of the concurrent operations
TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 64;
// Setup the transfer context and track the upoload progress
SingleTransferContext context = new SingleTransferContext();
context.ProgressHandler = new Progress<TransferStatus>((progress) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Bytes uploaded: {0}", progress.BytesTransferred);
});
// Upload a local blob
var task = TransferManager.UploadAsync(
    sourcePath, destBlob, null, context, CancellationToken.None);
task.Wait();
```

Learn More:

[Develop for Azure File storage with .Net](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/README.md)

[Storage Client Library Reference for .NET - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/)

If you are copying a blob to a file, or a file to a blob, you must use a shared access signature (SAS) to authenticate the source object, even if you are copying within the same storage account.

Answer (score 0):

> have a reference to the blob storage, as well as the uri of the file I want to move to the file storage

[CloudFile class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.file.cloudfile?view=azurestorage-8.1.3) enables us to initialize a new instance of the CloudFile class using an absolute URI to the file. You can refer to the following sample code to copy blob to Azure file.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("{connection_string}");

CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("source.txt");
blockBlob.OpenRead();        

CloudFile desfile = new CloudFile(new Uri("https://{account_name}.file.core.windows.net/myfiles/des.txt"), new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials("{sasToken}"));

desfile.StartCopy(blockBlob);
```

Comment: I get a 404 not found exception on the last line, but the file is definitely there.